# NIC firmware version on my DL380 G5

Tags: nic, firmware, hp-proliant

I am trying to figure out what is my current NIC firmware version.

If I run the latest firmware upgrade from HP, I get the following:
[image]

**It doesn't tell me the current version.**

If I try to check it from Device Manager, I get this:
[image]

**That's the driver version, not the hardware firmware version.**

If I reboot the computer, I don't see the NIC firmware during the POST..

How would I go about finding the current firmware version...

Thanks a lot!
Toast

Comment: In the first picture, what did it do when you clicked "Install?"  The message says that will display the installed version... did it?

Comment: Hello, very good question, I forgot to mention that I do not want to upgrade, I just want to see the current firmware version.  (So basically I never clicked "install") Thanks!

Comment: You'll *probably* get a chance to cancel the installation, so you could try it and see what happens.

Comment: Ward you were right... (VERY late reply lol)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found it.

For those who're interested, the firmware can be found in the **HP System Management Homepage** utility

Doh..

Comment: Any chance of getting this marked as the correct answer so it doesn't pop up on the front page?

Answer (score 0):

If you run HP Insight Diagnostics (survey) you can view the NIC firmware. Mine is showing 1.9.6